# How can I decrease this timer by one second after it starts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

How can I decrease this timer by one second after it starts?

I want to create a timer that changes after the button is triggered and decrements one second each time it is clicked? How should I write the function? I have done it's work to start but I don't know how to decrease its seconds with each click.
This is my code:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import Button from "../components/Button";

interface Props {
  setTime: (time: string) => void;
}

function Body({ setTime }: Props) {
  const Ref = useRef(null);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState("00:00:00");
  const getTimeRemaining = (e: string) => {
    const total = Date.parse(e) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24);

    return {
      total,
      hours,
      minutes,
      seconds,
    };
  };

  const startTimer = (e: string) => {
    const { total, hours, minutes, seconds } = getTimeRemaining(e);

    if (total >= 0) {
      setTimer(
        (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) +
          ":" +
          (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) +
          ":" +
          (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds)
      );
    }
  };

  const clearTimer = (e: string) => {
    setTimer("00:00:10");

    if (Ref.current) clearInterval(Ref.current);
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      startTimer(e);
    }, 1000);
    Ref.current = id;
  };

  const getDeadTime = () => {
    const deadline = new Date();
    deadline.setSeconds(deadline.getSeconds() + 3602);
    return deadline;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTime(timer);
  }, [timer]);

  const start = () => {
    clearTimer(getDeadTime());
  };

  const decrease = useMemo(() => {
    // console.log(e);
    const deadline = new Date();
    deadline.setSeconds(deadline.getSeconds() - 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {Ref.current ? (
        <Button onClick={()=> decrease}>Decrease</Button>
      ) : (
        <Button onClick={start}>Start</Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Body;
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the code you provided is not even compilable, Typescript found a few issues and due to that i was unable to help you fast. But anyway, things should be done much easier. And be careful about intervals and other things that should be cleared or unsubscribed, pretty easy to get a memory leaks or bugs.

```
function Body({ setTime }: Props) {
  const [startDateMs, setStartDateMs] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [endDateMs, setEndDateMs] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const timerText = useMemo<string>(() => {
    const defaults = "00:00:00";

    if (!startDateMs || !endDateMs) return defaults;

    const total = endDateMs - startDateMs;

    if (total <= 0) return defaults;

    const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24);

    return (
      (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) +
      ":" +
      (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) +
      ":" +
      (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds)
    );
  }, [startDateMs, endDateMs]);

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    const now = Date.now();
    setStartDateMs(now);
    setEndDateMs(now + 10 * 1000); // 10 sec
  }, []);

  const decrease = useCallback(() => {
    setEndDateMs((prev) => {
      if (!prev) return prev;
      return prev - 1000;
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!startDateMs || !endDateMs || endDateMs - startDateMs <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setEndDateMs((prev) => {
        if (!prev) return prev;
        return prev - 1000;
      });
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [startDateMs, endDateMs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!endDateMs || !startDateMs) return;

    if (endDateMs - startDateMs <= 0) {
      setStartDateMs(null);
      setEndDateMs(null);
    }
  }, [endDateMs, startDateMs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTime(timerText);
  }, [timerText, setTime]);

  return (
    <div>
      {startDateMs && endDateMs ? (
        <button onClick={decrease}>Decrease</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React TS Timer component]